# Delete causes StaleStateException

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

We a re using Grails which of course uses hibernate for its O/R.  In one instance we have multiple requests trying to delete the same object. The first thread will delete and the second thread that tries to delete the object throws a StaleStateException. This is as expected.  According to doc:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/envers/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/StaleStateException.html

This exception:  `Also occurs if we try delete or update a row that does not exist.`

Now, in our case it is not an exception. We don't care it has already been deleted.  We don't want to have to put in a check before the delete and we just want to put in exception handling because it is not really an exception.

What we would really like to do is not have this exception throw if a delete is attempted and the object is not there.

Is there any way to do this with Grails / Gorm?

The best ideal I have is to do the delete with just a bit of SQL of HSQL rather than use a hibernate / grails API.

Any better ones?

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch the exception in the thread:

```
try {
    YourDomain.withTransaction { status ->

        ...

        yourDomainInstance.delete()

        ...

        }
} catch (org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException olfe) {
log.warn(olfe.toString())
} catch (org.hibernate.StaleStateException staleStateException) {
log.warn(staleStateException.toString())
}
```

Comment: I had thought about that but would really prefer if exception was never thrown.

Comment: Well to totally remove the exception you can remote it from hibernate source code and recompile it. The stacktrace tell you exactly in what file and line hibernate generate the exception.